# About theme option in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, web-deployment-project

I am learning wordpress by myself. I have a question about theme option for theme development project.

I want to know that is it very important to create a theme option system in theme development project? Is it compulsory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not compulsory, as you can always make the page or project private. It depends on your objectives. If you want to create a theme that applies to the whole system, this can be accessed from settings.

Comment: Thanks for your co-operation.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depending on you but this option very useful and make easy to customize the theme... without this  you may be need hard work.